# Why was I able to boot OEM Windows 10 from an SSD which I took from another laptop?

Tags: windows-10, boot, oem

I had an old, broken Asus laptop from 2015 which I kept because I thought of repairing it or selling it for parts some day. The day never came and now I can't be bothered to disassemble it so what I chose to do was take out the M.2 SSD to use as a fast (though small) external drive.

I put the SSD in the case and wondered what would happen if I tried to boot my current computer with it. I hooked up the USB external case I put the SSD in to the computer. It turned out to start just fine. Why? Weren't OEM Windows editions tied to the serial number of the CPU? Did this change? Could I expect the system to stop working at some point or refuse to update?

Comment: Sounds like your machine booted normally and this M.2 was just additional storage.  How did you determine you actually boot from it?

Comment: By the wallpaper, actually

Answer (score -2):

A windows installation is not tied to the hardware it is installed on. If it was tied to the hardware upgrading computers would be impossible. Also the the operating system (windows) shouldent stop working or refuse to update unless the it is discontinued.

Hope this awnsers your question :)

Comment: Doesn't that make OEM Windows 10 different from the BOX edition only in the license you agree to? Also, what I meant was not that you could not upgrade the hardware, only the CPU.

Comment: Im not 100% sure on this but i think that oem versions of windows are just packaged with content or whatever from the oem company.  Also i dont really know what you mean by "only the cpu" but you can upgrade the cpu as long as it is compatible with the hardware generally the operating system wont be effected negatively

Comment: @TheBigBear390 - You are incorrect. OEM licenses cannot be transferred to new hardware.  However, that doesn’t mean they won’t boot, they will just be in an inactivated state.

Comment: @OldSSDUser - There really are no restrictions on what hardware you can upgrade with an OEM windows license.  The only hardware you cannot upgrade is the motherboard.  However, if your actually able to upgrade the processor, is an entirely different issue altogether